# How to arrange css priority in ODOO, when installing modules?

Tags: css, less, odoo, odoo-9

Odoo version: 9 community

I defined style for **"#o_shop_collapse_category li a"** but, it's not loading last, the style loaded is the one defined in **"/website_sale/static/src/css/website_sale.css"**.

When I defined my module, it depends of website_sale, so.... my module is installed last, and the css file is defined with **last()** so my style should be last defined in the **website.assets_frontend.0.css**

My style is the following:

```
#o_shop_collapse_category li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 4px 6px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

and it is load like this

```
<template id="celuphone_style" name="Celuphone style" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
    <xpath expr="link[last()]" position="after">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/client_CELUPHONE/static/less/style.less" type="text/less"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

The question is **how Odoo define modules priorities** at the time to compile less files

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should just add priority to template definition?

```
<template id="celuphone_style" name="Celuphone style" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" priority="999">
    <xpath expr="link[last()]" position="after">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/client_CELUPHONE/static/less/style.less" type="text/less"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```